# Scrape data from script tag by cheerio

Tags: javascript, node.js, web-scraping, cheerio

How can I scrape data from string like this

```js
<script type="application/json" class="js-react-on-rails-component" data-component-name="ItemPriceHeading">
  {
    "price":"29.0",
    "discountedPrice":null,
    "offerPrice":null,
    "totalPrice":"29.0",
    "currency":"PLN"
  }
</script>
```

I need to scrape "price" and "currency" values, but I can't understand how to do it.

I can scrape all strings, but how do I extract only selected parameters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just select the `<script>` tag with cheerio and then get the text and parse it like json:

Here is an example:

```js
const cheerio = require("cheerio");
const $ = cheerio.load(
    `<script type="application/json" class="js-react-on-rails-component" data-component-name="ItemPriceHeading">{"price":"29.0","discountedPrice":null,"offerPrice":null,"totalPrice":"29.0","currency":"PLN"}</script>`
);
const myJSON = JSON.parse(
    $('script[data-component-name="ItemPriceHeading"]').text()
);
console.log(myJSON);
```

myJSON variable should be equal to:

```json
{
  price: '29.0',
  discountedPrice: null,
  offerPrice: null,
  totalPrice: '29.0',
  currency: 'PLN'
}
```